# SQL needs group by, but i dont see how it applies

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have tried many times without success.

The question is

15. List the customer id for the Ontario customers that have placed 2 or more orders in 2014

and my answer is

```
SELECT Customer.CustId 
FROM Customer 
   INNER JOIN Orders ON Customer.CustId = Orders.CustId 
WHERE (Prov = 'ON' AND YEAR( Orders.OrderDate) = '2014') 
HAVING COUNT (Orders.CustId) > 2;
```

but i keep getting an error because there isn't a group by clause, but I don't get where would that play in the answer.

Attached is the physical schema

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsSgu.jpg

Comment: The question can be answered in current format (after edit), but it is better to include table schema as text, not as image. For more complex questions, you receive better answers if we are able to actually test the queries (create tables, run the script).

Answer (score 0):

HAVING is only used in conjunction with a GROUP BY.  Just include the COUNT(...) > 2 as part of your WHERE clause.  So your query would look like:

```
SELECT Customer.CustId 
FROM Customer 
   INNER JOIN Orders ON Customer.CustId = Orders.CustId 
WHERE (Prov = 'ON' AND YEAR( Orders.OrderDate) = '2014') AND COUNT (Orders.CustId) > 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error makes sense, since `HAVING` clause is applied only when grouping (`GROUP BY`). A version of the query that should work is the following:

```
SELECT Customer.CustId, COUNT(1) Cnt
FROM Customer C
   INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.CustId = O.CustId 
GROUP BY C.CustId
WHERE Prov = 'ON' AND YEAR(Orders.OrderDate) = 2014 
HAVING COUNT (1) > 2;
```

To optimize a little bit, you should avoid scalar functions in conditions, since any index on that column cannot be used:

```
SELECT Customer.CustId, COUNT(1) Cnt
FROM Customer C
   INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.CustId = O.CustId 
GROUP BY C.CustId
WHERE Prov = 'ON' AND (Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20141231') 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer.CustId 
FROM Customer 
   INNER JOIN Orders ON Customer.CustId = Orders.CustId 
WHERE (Prov = 'ON' AND YEAR(Orders.OrderDate) = 2014) 
GROUP BY Customer.CustId   --<-- you need to add this group by here 
HAVING COUNT (Orders.CustId) > 2;
```